# Attribute Error: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'

Tags: python, pycharm, attributeerror, discord.py

```
from discord.ext import commands

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='{')

@client.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Pong!")
```

I'm extremely new to Python and I'm currently learning how to program a discord bot with discord.py rewrite. I followed this code from a YouTuber named Lucas. This is his exact code. His seems to work but for some reason, my PyCharm still says that client has no attribute command. May someone teach me how to fix it?

This is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danie/PycharmProjects/Discord Tutorial/bot.py", line 93, in <module>
    @client.command()
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'command'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With my knowledge, if you wish to continue using the `client` part of discord.py, then you should try the `on_message` part of it, An example:

```
async def on_message(message):
    if message.content.startswith('{ping'):
        await message.channel.send('pong')
```

But if you want a reletivly easier alternative, (At least it makes more sense to me) You could try `@bot.command` Example:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
TOKEN = ''
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='{')

@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx):
    await ctx.send('pong')
```

One great thing about `@bot.command` is its easier to get input.

If you want to get what the user says after they do the command, then you could do.

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, *, variableName):
    await ctx.send(f'You said {variableName}')
```

And if you want an error message if they mess up you could do

```
@bot.command()
async def ping(ctx, *, variableName):
    await ctx.send(f'You said {variableName}')
@ping.error
async def ping_error(ctx, error):
    ctx.send("Please enter something after the command")
```

And in my experience, it is much easier to find help on stackoverflow if you are using `@bot.command` as most other people use it as well. However, back to you wanting to use `@client.command` I do not know about that. However, if you want to switch over to `@bot.command` then I'm sure you can look up what you want to do on either google or stackoverflow and look until you find one for `@bot.command` Which shouldn't be that long.